# Xcode swift user specific data and access

Tags: swift, user-interface, parse-platform

I'm new to Xcode and swift. I'm trying to setup user specific layouts and access to view controllers. I've been googling around for a few weeks but not found what I need (probably a terminology issue). 
In short I'm after information on how to change a menu to have what the user has access to. 
So currently I have a menu that brings up view controllers, some users should have access to one, but by default or setting the others shouldn't. I'm using parse.com as my credential infrastructure for now (may change). And I though it should be achievable through roles, but I have failed to find information on how to achieve this.

Any help or "it's clearly stated here" would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't clarify what problem you faced. Now I guess that you want UI of Application difference depend on user logged? Right?

Comment: Hi vien vu, yes a starting block would be how to show or hide elements depending on user.

Comment: Please try to narrow down the problem and post what you have tried. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, we can have many way to approach. Now I can suggest to way to you.

1. Solution 1:
   You can separate UI for kind of user to differen storyboard. Depend on
   kind of user you will load storyboard for it. Maybe it will duplicate    alot. But it is the way will work.
2. Solution 2:
   You should keep a variable to detect kind of user. In swift you can use `enum` and keep it in a `singleton`. And when you to controller, depend on this variable you will show hide component you want. In this case maybe you have to handle a lot element on UI to achieve what you want.

It is my idea. Hope this help!

Comment: Hi All, sorry for my delay. I appreciate the comments. I am sure it's a very broad question, but vien has given me some stuff to research. Hopefully this leads me down the road to the answer. Cheers all

Comment: Cheers again new, was saving it for the celebration of getting it working